# How can a program detect that it is running on Citrix?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, citrix

I am creating a program, which may or may not run inside a Citrix instance. The program needs to detect this, because it needs to behave in a different way on Citrix. How can it be detected in a reliable way? So far, my best guess was to check whether the computer has a C-drive.

Comment: Removed virtualenv tag, which seems to be Python-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool(os.environ.get('citrix_version'))
```

I think this is the best way to detect in python.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to know whether your application runs in a XenApp (aka Presentation Server / Metaframe) session?

Checking for the existence of drive C: is not the right way to do it. Historically, the drives letters on Citrix terminal servers were often remapped, e.g. from C: to M:. But this is not "en vogue" any more.

Please see [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186153/api-for-determining-if-app-is-running-on-citrix-or-terminal-services/4188982#4188982) for the correct way to determine the **session type**.

If instead you want to determine if XenApp/Presentation Server is **installed**, look up the corresponding registry values as described in [Citrix Knowledgebase article CTX107570](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX107570).