# Determing whether app is running on a remote system

Tags: java, remote-desktop, jogl, citrix

I'm working with a Java webstart application and we're trying to disable JOGL when the application starts if we're running on a remote system such as Citrix or rdesktop.

I have the code in place to disable JOGL, but I'm having trouble determining when it is running through Citrix.   The system properties appear to be the same as a running the application from my local machine.

Any ideas or suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the link from Helge above, I was able to identify an environment variable that I can test from within Java.

```
String SESSION_NAME_KEY = "SESSIONNAME";
String sessionname = System.getenv(SESSION_NAME_KEY);

if(sessionname != null && 
     (sessionname.startsWith("ICA") || sessionname.startsWith("RDP")))
    //Disable JOGL
```

I'm not sure this covers every situation, but it should work for what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186153/api-for-determining-if-app-is-running-on-citrix-or-terminal-services/4188982#4188982) for a way to determine whether your product runs in a Citrix XenApp session.

Comment: It it's a JWS app it *may* be running on my Linux or Mac box, in which case `WTSQuerySessionInformation` doesn't exist.

Comment: We are running on Linux boxes, in addition to windows.