# Is it possible to run programs locally from a terminal services remote app?

Tags: windows, shellexecute, terminal-services, remoteapp

First, I guess I'd have to figure out if I'm [running remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186153/api-for-determining-if-app-is-running-on-citrix-or-terminal-services) and second I'd have to figure out whether my remote connection is a standalone remote app or an app running on a terminal server (that may be tricky).

But, once I've figured out all those awful things, is there a way to run a windows function like [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) locally instead of remotely?

The reason I'd want to do this is because I launch a web browser to view rather high bandwidth things that require javascript and flash and certain sysadmins who administer our product aren't too keen on having to make unnecessary and insecure modifications to their terminal server farm.

Comment: Note: Off topic vote has drawn the ire of poster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the clients are running Windows and you can install software on them.

See [Remote Desktop Services Virtual Channels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383546%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: You don't happen to have any idea which DLL has the VirtualChannelInit function?  I'm a delphi programmer so I'm trying to implement this via the JEDI win32 api, the wtsapi32 is all implemented, but MSDN says the functions for the client side are in CClient.H and I don't know where that's pointing to.

Comment: Crap, I guess I have to write it myself.  I wonder if I'm the first Delphi programmer to try this...

Comment: The documentation for VirtualChannelInit says "Remote Desktop Services provides a pointer to a VirtualChannelInit function in the CHANNEL_ENTRY_POINTS structure passed to your VirtualChannelEntry entry point."  So you don't need to link to a DLL.  Most likely, the function is in the executable that is calling *your* DLL!

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out, thanks - only 6 functions and 1 struct, not too much of an awful API to implement.  Haven't quite got it working yet though. Lots of cryptic errors.  This was pretty handy: http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=9316

Answer (score 1):

There is a free tool that does exactly what you want. I got reference from TechNet forums, it's named Remote Executer from http://www.mqtechnologies.com

Good luck