# Detecting execution into TerminalServer and environment variables

Tags: c#, .net, environment-variables, terminal-services

I'm trying to use the environment variable SESSIONNAME to detect if we are executing inside a TerminalServer session. The method `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SESSIONNAME");` is returning `RDP-Tcp#0` but when I check the environment variables with `SET` I cannot see that environment variable.

See the following screenshot:

[image]

Somebody has an idea of what's going on? Or maybe I should try to detect the TerminalService hosting in another way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help in terms of detection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186153/api-for-determining-if-app-is-running-on-citrix-or-terminal-services As for your discrepancy, is Visual studio installed on the terminal server as well?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson yes, it is. Thanks for the link.